# Use case extends or include

Tags: include, uml, extends, use-case, use-case-diagram

I have 3 actors: `User A`, `User B` and `Admin` and the use case `view photo` that is linked with each actors. Now, I want to add a use case `add to favourites`, and this use case can be activated only by `User A`.

Should the use case `add to favourites` extends or include `View Photo`?
The `User A` goals are view photo and add photo to favourites after view it, if he wants.
What is the best solution?

Comment: The  very general duplicate is not super helpful, with its 21 answers going in all directions (many diverging directions) without any of it being accepted, and some being even obviously wrong :-/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is whether `add to favourite` is a use case at all. Indeed, this looks more like a feature in the user interface of the photo viewer than a user goal on its own.

If you think it is, and given your narrative, then `«extends»` seems to be more suitable since it adds some optional behavior to the behavior of viewing the photo. A constraint on the extension point could limit the extension to only some kind of actors.

A better option in my view would be to make `manage favourites` a separate use case. Indeed, id yiu think that the favourites are an important goal, then give it the right visibility. How this goal is implemented in the user interface (a use-case is not a user interface !!) is not important, and you could easily show that only one kind of actors is associated with it.

This being said your diagram will anyway be more ambiguous than you think: when several actors are associated with the same use case it is unspecified if all the actors are involved at the same time (ex: the seller and the buyer in an auction), or if the actors intervene successively in the execution of a use case (e.g one actor completes some operations started by anither actor), or if it means that only one of the actors is involved.

Comment: Thank you. Making a separate use case manage favourites, should this include view photo? So that the user first views the photo and then adds it to favorites.

Comment: That's exactly the point: the use case is not a feature, or window. The use-case is the goal for which actors use the system. By definition, the use case is a set of behaviors. And nothing prevents you to design a user interface that implements two use-cases, e.g viewing a photo and adding a photo to the favourite. If on contrary you design the use-case according to your user interface, you create a rigidity that will prevent creative solution. You could imagine several different ways to add photos to the favorites and not all of them require the traditional viewing a photo and marking.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not very clear to me. If the actor's goal is to add the photo to his favorites, is the following use case description correct? Description: the actor views the photo and decides whether to add it to his favorites. I think in my system this use case description and the use case itself are independent of the user interface, because they describe the actor's goal. If this use case is correct does it make sense to include view photo? If it is not correct, what could be a description of the manage favorites use case? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: If you think that it's an independent goal but that it is always achieved in relation with some other use cases, independently of the user interface, you could very well go for the extend. It is your model and I'm not here to judge. If you'd go for a separate independent use case, you could formulate it slightly differently: "The actor decides to add or remove some photos to the favourites to view them later. Adding a favourite could for example be performed when viewing a specific photo, or by selecting several photos when viewing a gallery, or when uploading a new photo".

Comment: The advantage of the second option is that I'm not biased with one particular solution/feature that I have in my mind, but I keep my attention on user goals, remaining open for creative ways of doing it.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand that I don't have to be biased about a specific solution.